macOS XCode 16 breaks dynamic_cast for `final` types, defined in shared library
Let's say we have shared library with the following very simple Type.h:
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct Derived final : Base
{
    Derived();
};

, Type.cpp:
#include "Type.h"

Derived::Derived() = default;

and main.cpp program:
#include "Type.h"

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> pr;
    pr = std::make_shared<Derived>();

    auto dyncast = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(pr.get());
    if (dyncast) {
        std::cout << "OK\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "!!! FAIL\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

Compiled with -O2 flag:
> clang++ -dynamiclib -L. -std=gnu++20 -O2 -o libOut.dylib Type.cpp
> clang++ -o out main.cpp -L. -lOut -O2 -std=gnu++20
> ./out

For some reason, with XCode 16 the program fails to dynamic_cast and outputs fail line.
The following "fixes" the issue:

removing final from Derived declaration
inlining Derived constructor
adding other virtual member function to Derived
building without -O2
downgrading XCode to v.15

As of my understanding, some sort of optimization takes place here, causing dynamic_cast to fail, but, IMO, this looks like bug, and a huge one. Am I missing something?
Is there some sort of workaround/compiler flag to make this work?
Thank you.

For the compiler you are using as an implementation detail, the RTTI information is generated in the translation unit of the first non-inline virtual function.  If there are no non-inline virtual functions, that information is generated in every translation unit.  The dynamic_cast compares the address of the RTTI information, presuming that it gets coalesced into one-and-the-same object.  But the two different executables have their own copy of that RTTI object, so the dynamic_cast fails. Try: add a non-inline non-implicit virtual destructor in the Derived class.

I suspect problem is virtual ~Base() = default; in header file which leads to virtual table defined per translation unit/library what makes RTTI information inconsistent and dynamic_cast failing. Drop default and define destructor in single cpp file and it should be fine. Your example is not Complete, so this is not valid MCVE.

@MarekR Added MCVE. Dropping default doesn't help here.

@Eljay yes, any virtual non-inline function fixes the issue, not just destructor, as I've mentioned in original post, but I still don't see how this is expected behaviour. In other words am I doing something illegal here, so that dynamic_cast breaks?:) I'd expect it to work without adding anything here.

You're not doing anything wrong as per the C++ standard.  Your platform's implementation of shared libraries and its dynamic library loader and how objects are statically pre-linked within those binaries either cannot support the C++ abstract machine requirements or requires additional effort from you to thwart your compiler/linkers optimizations that are performing premature optimizations that really have to be deferred until the binaries are loaded (resolving weak links).

Offtopic: your MCVE is missing #include <iostream> and #include<memory>.

Problem is that virtual desturctors are implicitly defined in header.
This leads to situation where each library/executable has own virtual table for given type. As a result there is problem with RTTI and dynamic_cast fails.
I've reproduced your issue on my MacOS machine and after introducing fixes below it works as it should:
Type.h
#pragma once

struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base();
};

struct Derived final : Base
{
    Derived();
    ~Derived();
};

Type.cpp
#include "Type.h"

Base::~Base() = default;
Derived::Derived() = default;
Derived::~Derived() = default;

In this form you will have warranty there is only one virtual table for each type and it is inside of libOut.dylib

The fix is not as easy when the types involved are template instantiations. The fix needs extern declaration of template instantiations plus explicit instantiation.

@Nitesh question do not ask about templates, so what is your point?

I too faced this problem with types which are template instantiations. So, I just noted that the problem would need different fix in that case.
